# Asserting with..as clause in Python

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

So, having the unittest.mock and the code

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, port) as sftp:
             sftp.get("filename")
```

... one can assert `Connection.assert_called_with(host, username, password, port)`.
But assertion `Connection.assert_called_with(host, username, password, port).get("filename")` fails.

How do I assert that?

Comment: Please post a complete runable example where is clear what you `patch`/`mock` and how. Like it is the question have no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would like to [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) `pysftp.Connection` reference.

Here is an example of how you can do your test:

```
>>> import pysftp
>>> from mock import *

>>> with patch("pysftp.Connection") as mock_connection:
...     with pysftp.Connection("1.2.3.4", "user", "pwd", 12345) as sftp:
...         sftp.get("filename")
...     mock_connection.assert_called_with("1.2.3.4", "user", "pwd", 12345)
...     sftp.get.assert_called_with("filename")
... 
<MagicMock name='Connection().__enter__().get()' id='139907730030992'>
```

Because `sftp` object is a `MagicMock` you can use it directly. As you can see in the log `sftp` is exactly the same of

```
mock_connection.return_value.__enter__.return_value
```

- `Connection` -> `mock_connection`
- `()` -> `return_value`